"Username" to be filled by OEM, no administrator rights anymore
I use ubuntu studio.
After a system update the system takes verry long time to startup, so i started in recovery mode. After that it starts slowly and now i have only user "my user name@ to be filled by OEM. i cannot acces any rights anymore. can i role it back to my old user name?

Please [edit] your question and add details where exactly you see this. Showing a screenshot (or a photo taken with a different device) might help to understand your problem.
